Hook setenv(), getenv() using C code during runtime to make them thread safe
As it is already painfully known, modifying the process environment in a multi-threaded application during runtime is asking for trouble. However, not always we can control who accesses that.
In this situation, we rely on some 3rd party libraries to which we only have binary distribution (.so files). Unfortunately, they tend to abuse the setenv() function which sporadically causes our logger to crash during a strftime() call. Sometimes, it may crash once in a few days; sometimes it can crash several times per day; but the stack trace always ends up in getenv(), which as you can imagine is not really pleasant for users.
What came to my mind as a potential fix is to hook setenv() and getenv() functions and use a global mutex before calling the original implementation. I'm looking for a more future-proof method that does not contain assembly.
On Windows, I would easily do that by using Microsoft Detours, but I'm not aware of any easy method regarding the *nix world.
In general, I would like to have a working solution for Android C library(Bionic), Apple Clang with their C library and Linux with glibc. Android is my greatest priority as the crashes there are many times more often compared to any other platform. Also, to mention that LD_PRELOAD is not an option; it should be fully C code(of course platform specific) solution from the main executable which I can execute before starting any complex routines.
P.S. I know with such kind of hooks I cannot protect from a direct usage of the global environ variable, but I believe it is not directly used by the 3rd parties.
UPDATE: I want to explicitly state that our codebase does not modify the environment. No usages of setenv/putenv etc. The problem is coming from the 3rd parties which I've mentioned.

Maybe you should wrap the calls to the problematic library functions instead?

There is no "fully C code solution" to the problem, because you're supposing that there will be two different functions in the same program with the same name, both with external linkage, and also because you propose to provide your own definitions of names that are reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.  C expressly refuses to define the behavior of such a program, so you have only implementation-specific behaviors to work with.

Side note: do not overlook putenv() and unsetenv(), and maybe even clearenv(), at least not without verifying that they are not called.  Possibly GNU-specific secure_getenv(), too.

Side note 2: POSIX says that getenv() is thread safe, though the environment modification functions are not.

Is strftime_l() available to you?  If so, can you modify your code to use it?  It should not be affected by environment changes because you explicitly pass a locale to it.

You can interpose setenv to remember in a thread-local variable what TZ is being set to (and, if regular setenv operation is desired, to forward all calls to the underlying setenv). And you can interpose strftime to call strftime_l, passing it the stored thread-local value of TZ. If strftime_l is not available, your interposed strftime can lock, set TZ, call the underlying strftine, reset TZ, and unlock. Then your interposed setenv would also need to use a lock when using the underlying setenv to set TZ.

@JohnBollinger By a C solution I don't mean like standard C. I'm completely aware it is going to be platform specific code, I just don't want to involve assembly.

@JonathanLeffler The locale is not the issue. It is the TZ fetching - strftime() calls implicitly tzset() which calls getenv("TZ") which then crashes when other code is doing setenv() and friends.
@EricPostpischil And here I'm asking how to exactly do that? I can't control what the binary only 3rd party libraries are doing. That's why I want to hook the functions in order to redirect all calls.

Side note: for diagnostic logs it's often acceptable to use UTC timestamps. If the app also communicates with a server, not having to deal with timezones when comparing logs becomes an actual benefit.

@tevemadar Yes, we log in UTC time. However, strftime() does not care. It will always call tzset().

"method that does not contain assembly" - that sounds strange, given that you have no problem with Detours. It definitely patches up compiled code.

@MSalters I'm perfectly fine if it is wrapped in some 3rd party library. I don't want to use it myself, because I don't want to deal with different CPUs. :)

@TheStorm: You interpose the calls. There are existing questions on that. Searching for “interpose”, “interposition”, and “interposing” will find them.

I don't follow.  In the question you say no LD_PRELOAD, and then you say you mean you're ok with platform-specific features but you want to avoid assembly, which is a totally different set of constraints.  And since you acknowledge that platform-specific features will be needed, you're actually asking for three different solutions.  I'm left uncertain what kind of solutions you will actually accept, but certain that the question is too broad.

How about filing an issue on the 3rd party developer's support site and let them fix their bug?

@KungPhoo I believe that many people are suffering from the issue I have, so if we get some way to fix/workaround it in general, that would be great.

Could you use snprintf instead of strftime for your application?

“Hooking” functions as you ask is called interposing. Since you ask about multiple platforms, I am not going to speak to that here except to say that searching for “[c] interposition”, “[c] interposing”, and “[c] interpose” will show you questions about that. (There are tags for this, including interposing, function-interposition, and library-interposition, but they seem little used, so I expect the preceding searches will be more productive.)
When you have interposition working, interpose setenv:

If the name being set is “TZ”, save the new value using a thread-local variable (that was initialized to either a null pointer or a copy of TZ at program startup or whatever value you desire).
Acquire a lock.
Call the underlying setenv, passing it the unchanged parameters.
Release the lock.

And interpose strftime:

Acquire a lock (the same one as above).
Call getenv to get TZ, saving it in a temporary copy.
Call the underlying setenv to set TZ from the thread-local value. (If the thread-local value is a null pointer, use the original value of TZ from program startup, saved at program startup, or whatever value you desire.)
Call the underlying strftime, passing it the unchanged parameters.
Call the underlying setenv to restore TZ from the saved value.
Release the lock.

Notes
If your problem is just that the libraries are calling setenv to set names other than TZ and that sometimes causes strftime to crash, you can remove the TZ manipulations from above and reduce each interposing routine to just lock, call the underlying routine, and unlock.
If the library strftime calls setenv and, due to the interposition method, gets your interposing setenv, you will have a thread trying to acquire a lock it already has. You will want to detect that in your setenv and just pass the call through to the underlying setenv without taking the lock and without releasing it afterward.

We log the time in UTC format so I really don't care about the time zone, neither I modify it. The problem is that strftime() calls tzset() which calls getenv("TZ") implicitly and that makes a data race with the other 3rd parties which are doing their setenv() stuff.
I didn't knew hooks are also called "interposing". I have checked out the links you gave but I see only LD_PRELOAD for Linux and DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES for MacOS and I explicitly stated that I cannot use these methods in production builds. It have to be something done directly from the code of the main executable.

@TheStorm: You may be able to effect the necessary control of library loading on macOS by writing one executable that sets the environment variables and then launches the primary executable. In any case, Stack Overflow is for specific questions, not complete solutions. I have given you a method for dealing with setenv and strftime once you have interposed them. If you need solutions for interposing on Android, macOS, and Linux and cannot find them in existing questions, you can ask a new specific question for each platform.

Sorry, but you didn't told me anything which I already didn't knew. I explicitly stated what kind of solution I seek and what I don't. If you don't know it or can't point out to at least an answer for a single platform, then it is pointless to reply.

@TheStorm: Nonetheless, you will need to ask for each platform separately.

I don't see a point to ask the same question 4 times with the only difference being a platform...

@TheStorm: One reason is to keep answers specific for the benefit of future users, so that search results for problems on a specific platform will turn up specific answers instead of potentially long multiple-system answers dealing with irrelevant complications to that user. You are one user, but Stack Overflow is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers for the future, so one answer may serve many users. Regardless of the reasons, that is current policy. You can participate in policy discussions at the meta site.

Sorry but I don't agree with you that I should ask the same question 4 times with the only difference being the platform. Anyway, it seems you not only gave useless answer given the question I've asked, but you've also managed to close my question. Bravo!
I've updated it to remove the other platforms and leave only Android. I hope it is enough focused for you now...
